# Read, write, and... 'O'?

Tags: performance, terminology

I have a disk activity monitoring tool (specifically [Process Hacker](https://processhacker.sourceforge.io/)) that is showing my program doing 0 kb/s of R(eading), 0kb/s of W(riting), and 20kb of 'O'. What's 'O'? Overwriting? Oopdating? Odorizing?

[image]

Comment: Use the [source](https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker/blob/master/ProcessHacker/sysscio.c#L149), Luke!  It evidently stands for "Other".  Now, what that actually *means* would require more digging.